# Pl/sql %RowType in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I have been trying to execute a Oracle Stored procedure  which returns %ROWTYPE using JDBC, as i mentioned below

```
  OracleCallableStatement ocs = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("begin <PackageName>.procedureName(?,?,?,?); end; ");
  ocs.setString(1, "001");
  ocs.registerOutParameter(2,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
  ocs.registerOutParameter(3,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
  ***ocs.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.OTHER);*** /*here What do i need to put, i didn't find Wrapperclass which is compatible for %ROWTYPE*/

 ocs.executeUpdate(); 

 String newerrorcode =  ocs.getString(2);

System.out.println("\n ErrorCode = " + newerrorcode );
String newErrorDesc =  ocs.getString(3);

System.out.println("\n ErrorDesc = " + newErrorDesc );
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) ocs.getObject(4);
```

exception: that we are getting is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PR_APP_DATE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:202)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1005)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4735)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
at testSysBusinessDts.main(testSysBusinessDts.java:62)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer: use [JPublisher](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraarr.htm#i1057327), and map the types created by JPublisher, to the JDBC Connection type mapping.

The long answer: neither the JDBC specification nor the Oracle JDBC driver allows for custom (user-defined) types to be automagically converted into Java objects, and vice versa. A type mapping must be established for this, so that the driver can read and write to the connection in an appropriate manner. While the Oracle JDBC driver does allow for certain SQL types to be read and written to, using the `oracle.sql.*` classes, it cannot be applied to UDTs, for the structure of the UDTs cannot be known in advance. Using JPublisher resolves this problem for it creates classes that reflect the structure of the UDT; once these classes are taken into consideration by the Oracle JDBC driver, it can read the appropriate types from the result set, or may write objects of these types into the connection stream.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to what you're asking. The trick there was to declare a refcursor of the rowtype and declare the return as a cursor. [I've found the same result elsewhere, hope it helps you.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/294615/JDBC/java/JDBC-Stored-Procedure-Rowtype)